# What returned by calling `Object.getPrototypeOf` on a function?

Tags: javascript

What functions's `[[Prototype]]` points to?

In the below code, constructor function `b`'s `[[Prototype]]` points to constructor function `a`.

```js
class a{}
class b extends a{}

Object.getPrototypeOf(b)===a //true
```

Comment: It seems you already know, so what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the below code, constructor function `b`'s `[[Prototype]]` points to constructor function `a`.

Right, that's how `class` syntax works. It sets up two parallel lines of inheritance:

```
b −−−−−−−−−−−−−−> a −−−−−−−−−−−−−−> Function.prototype

b.prototype −−−−> a.prototype −−−−> Object.prototype
```

The prototype of function `b` is function `a` (which is how it inherits static methods). That's covered by the specification's abstract [ClassDefinitionEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation) operation (the function inheritance part is step 8(h)(iii) as of this writing) and the parts of the spec that call it.

The prototype of an ordinary function is `Function.prototype` (see [InstantiateOrdinaryFunctionObject](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiateordinaryfunctionobject)). Generator functions, `async` functions, and `async` generator functions inherit from prototypes that aren't directly exposed by a built-in property ([1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiategeneratorfunctionobject), [2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiateasyncfunctionobject), [3](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiateasyncgeneratorfunctionobject)).

Comment: Could you share a ECMA spec reference?

Comment: @leili - I've added them.

Answer (score 0):

The `[[Prototype]]` of `class B` is `class A`
This is how `static` inheritance work - statics missing on `class B` are taken from its `[[Prototype]]`, `class A`
[image]

The `.prototype` of `class B` is an instance of `class A` with assigned `{ constructor: class B }`
This is how instance inheritance works - properties missing on `B.prototype` are taken from its `[[Prototype]]`, `A { [[Prototype]]: A.prototype, constructor: class B }`
[image]